# XSLT for-each-group group-starting-with tail(current-group())

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

This is a follow up to Martin Honnen's answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77809283/xslt-preceding-sibling-how-to-get-previous-non-blank-value).

Here was my attempt at his suggestion:
[XSLT Fiddle link](https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet+xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A++version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A++xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A++exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A++expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A++%3Cxsl%3Aoutput+method%3D%22html%22+indent%3D%22yes%22+html-version%3D%225%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%3Cxsl%3Atemplate+match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0D%0A%09++%3Coutput%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3Cxsl%3Afor-each-group+select%3D%22%2F%2FRow%22+group-starting-with%3D%22Row%5Bnormalize-space%28Meter%29+and+normalize-space%28State%29%5D%22%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cgroup%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Cxsl%3Afor-each+select%3D%22current-group%28%29%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++++%3C%21--+tail+%3D+Returns+all+but+the+first+item+in+a+sequence.+--%3E+%0D%0A++++++++++%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates+select%3D%22tail%28current-group%28%29%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++++%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each%3E%0D%0A++++++%3C%2Fgroup%3E%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each-group%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3C%2Foutput%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate+match%3D%22Row%22%3E%0D%0A++++%3CRow%3E%0D%0A++++%3C%21--%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates+select%3D%22current-group%28%29%5B1%5D%21%28Meter%2C+State%29%2C+*%22%2F%3E--%3E%0D%0A++++++%3CMeter%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22current-group%28%29%5B1%5D%21%28Meter%29%22%2F%3E%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A++++++%3CState%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22current-group%28%29%5B1%5D%21%28State%29%22%2F%3E%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A++++++%3CStartDate%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22StartDate%22%2F%3E%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A++++++%3CVolume%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22Volume%22%2F%3E%3C%2FVolume%3E%0D%0A++++%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%3C%21--%0D%0A%09%3Cxsl%3Atemplate+match%3D%22Row%22%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%09%09%09%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates+select%3D%22current-group%28%29%5B1%5D%21%28Meter%2C+State%29%2C+*%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%09%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A++--%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3CVendorFile+xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fetc%2FVendorFile%22%3E%0D%0A++++%3CRow+xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CMeter%3E123%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CState%3ETX%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CStartDate%2F%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CVolume%2F%3E%0D%0A++++%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A++++%3CRow+xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CMeter%3E%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CState%3E%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CStartDate%3E1%2F1%2F2024%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CVolume%3E100%3C%2FVolume%3E%0D%0A++++%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A++++%3CRow+xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CMeter%3E%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CState%3E%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CStartDate%3E1%2F2%2F2024%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CVolume%3E110%3C%2FVolume%3E%0D%0A++++%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A++++%3CRow+xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CMeter%3E%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CState%3E%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CStartDate%3E1%2F3%2F2024%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CVolume%3E107%3C%2FVolume%3E%0D%0A++++%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A++++%3CRow+xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CMeter%3E456%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CState%3EOK%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CStartDate%2F%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CVolume%2F%3E%0D%0A++++%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A++++%3CRow+xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CMeter%3E%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CState%3E%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CStartDate%3E1%2F1%2F2024%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CVolume%3E200%3C%2FVolume%3E%0D%0A++++%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A++++%3CRow+xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CMeter%3E%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CState%3E%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CStartDate%3E1%2F2%2F2024%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CVolume%3E205%3C%2FVolume%3E%0D%0A++++%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A++++%3CRow+xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CMeter%3E%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CState%3E%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CStartDate%3E1%2F3%2F2024%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3CVolume%3E210%3C%2FVolume%3E%0D%0A++++%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FVendorFile%3E+&input-type=XML)

In spreadsheet form, the data looks like this:

[image]

In XML this is the data input:

```
<VendorFile xmlns="http://etc/VendorFile">
    <Row xmlns="">
        <Meter>123</Meter>
        <State>TX</State>
        <StartDate/>
        <Volume/>
    </Row>
    <Row xmlns="">
        <Meter></Meter>
        <State></State>
        <StartDate>1/1/2024</StartDate>
        <Volume>100</Volume>
    </Row>
    <Row xmlns="">
        <Meter></Meter>
        <State></State>
        <StartDate>1/2/2024</StartDate>
        <Volume>110</Volume>
    </Row>
    <Row xmlns="">
        <Meter></Meter>
        <State></State>
        <StartDate>1/3/2024</StartDate>
        <Volume>107</Volume>
    </Row>
    <Row xmlns="">
        <Meter>456</Meter>
        <State>OK</State>
        <StartDate/>
        <Volume/>
    </Row>
    <Row xmlns="">
        <Meter></Meter>
        <State></State>
        <StartDate>1/1/2024</StartDate>
        <Volume>200</Volume>
    </Row>
    <Row xmlns="">
        <Meter></Meter>
        <State></State>
        <StartDate>1/2/2024</StartDate>
        <Volume>205</Volume>
    </Row>
    <Row xmlns="">
        <Meter></Meter>
        <State></State>
        <StartDate>1/3/2024</StartDate>
        <Volume>210</Volume>
    </Row>
</VendorFile>
```

My attempted XSLT is this (I have included the group tags to help understand):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
     <output>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//Row" group-starting-with="Row[normalize-space(Meter) and normalize-space(State)]">
          <group>
              <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                  <!-- tail = Returns all but the first item in a sequence. --> 
                   <xsl:apply-templates select="tail(current-group())"/>
                  </xsl:for-each>
             </group>       
        </xsl:for-each-group>
     <output>    
    </xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="Row">
    <Row>
    <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]!(Meter, State), *"/>-->
      <Meter><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]!(Meter)"/></Meter>
      <State><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]!(State)"/></State>
      <StartDate><xsl:value-of select="StartDate"/></StartDate>
      <Volume><xsl:value-of select="Volume"/></Volume>
    </Row>
</xsl:template>

    
    <!--
    <xsl:template match="Row">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]!(Meter, State), *"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My current output is not what I want, but it's rather close.  It seems that the startdate and volumes are occurring 3 times for each group.

```
<output>
   <group>
      <Row><Meter>123</Meter><State>TX</State>
         <StartDate>1/1/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>100</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>123</Meter><State>TX</State>
         <StartDate>1/2/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>110</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>123</Meter><State>TX</State>
         <StartDate>1/3/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>107</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>123</Meter><State>TX</State>
         <StartDate>1/1/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>100</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>123</Meter><State>TX</State>
         <StartDate>1/2/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>110</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>123</Meter><State>TX</State>
         <StartDate>1/3/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>107</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>123</Meter><State>TX</State>
         <StartDate>1/1/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>100</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>123</Meter><State>TX</State>
         <StartDate>1/2/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>110</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>123</Meter><State>TX</State>
         <StartDate>1/3/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>107</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>123</Meter><State>TX</State>
         <StartDate>1/1/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>100</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>123</Meter><State>TX</State>
         <StartDate>1/2/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>110</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>123</Meter><State>TX</State>
         <StartDate>1/3/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>107</Volume>
      </Row>
   </group>
   <group>
      <Row><Meter>456</Meter><State>OK</State>
         <StartDate>1/1/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>200</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>456</Meter><State>OK</State>
         <StartDate>1/2/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>205</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>456</Meter><State>OK</State>
         <StartDate>1/3/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>210</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>456</Meter><State>OK</State>
         <StartDate>1/1/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>200</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>456</Meter><State>OK</State>
         <StartDate>1/2/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>205</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>456</Meter><State>OK</State>
         <StartDate>1/3/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>210</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>456</Meter><State>OK</State>
         <StartDate>1/1/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>200</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>456</Meter><State>OK</State>
         <StartDate>1/2/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>205</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>456</Meter><State>OK</State>
         <StartDate>1/3/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>210</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>456</Meter><State>OK</State>
         <StartDate>1/1/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>200</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>456</Meter><State>OK</State>
         <StartDate>1/2/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>205</Volume>
      </Row>
      <Row><Meter>456</Meter><State>OK</State>
         <StartDate>1/3/2024</StartDate>
         <Volume>210</Volume>
      </Row>
   </group>
</output>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main error is changing

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//Row" group-starting-with="Row[normalize-space(Meter) and normalize-space(State)]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="tail(current-group())"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

to

```
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//Row" group-starting-with="Row[normalize-space(Meter) and normalize-space(State)]">
      <group>
          <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
              <!-- tail = Returns all but the first item in a sequence. --> 
               <xsl:apply-templates select="tail(current-group())"/>
              </xsl:for-each>
         </group>       
    </xsl:for-each-group>
```

that way you have inserted a `for-each` which was not suggested but which for each item in the current group processes the tail of the current group.

Note also that I have reviewed the original answer and have improved the templates for `Row`s to

```
<xsl:template match="Row">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]!(Meter, State), * except (Meter, State)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

I would then suggest to add `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`.

Comment: Without the shallow-copy it was showing this: <Row>456OK1/1/2024200</Row> (no element names).  I must have added the current-group() based on some other reading I was doing. But in my real world app, I have lot's of mapping to do in each row.

Comment: For all "mappings" I would write further templates, that is why the `<xsl:apply-templates select="tail(current-group())"/>` and the `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]!(Meter, State), * except (Meter, State)"/>` is in there.

Comment: what does this mean?!
"current-group()[1]!(Meter, State), * except (Meter, State)"

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd, `current-group()[1]` selects the first item in the current group, so in this case that item that the group-starting-with pattern found that has filled out `Meter` and `State` data. The `!` is the XPath 3.1 simple map operator and simply selects the `Meter` and `State` elements from the first item in the current group. The rest of the sequence pushed through apply-templates then is all child elements `*` of the current node (`Row` element) with the exception of its own `Meter` and `State` child elements, because we use those from the 1st item in the group.

Comment: blimey....sorry is should have been more explicit with what was confusing me....it was the "* except (Meter,State)" never done that, I think i do something much more clumsy...nice

Answer (score 0):

Full working solution from Martin's reply above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <output>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//Row" group-starting-with="Row[normalize-space(Meter) and normalize-space(State)]">
          <!--group tag can be removed, it was just for understanding/debugging --> 
      <!--<group>-->
          <!-- tail = Returns all but the first item in a sequence. --> 
          <xsl:apply-templates select="tail(current-group())"/>
      <!--</group>-->
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        </output>

    </xsl:template>
    
<xsl:template match="Row">
    <Row>
    <!-- if not using copy, can do this: 
      <Meter><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]!(Meter)"/></Meter>
      <State><xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]!(State)"/></State>
      <StartDate><xsl:value-of select="StartDate"/></StartDate>
      <Volume><xsl:value-of select="Volume"/></Volume>
      -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]!(Meter, State), * except (Meter, State)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </Row>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT Fiddler: [Link](https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22html%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%20html-version%3D%225%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0D%0A%09%20%20%3Coutput%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3Cxsl%3Afor-each-group%20select%3D%22%2F%2FRow%22%20group-starting-with%3D%22Row%5Bnormalize-space%28Meter%29%20and%20normalize-space%28State%29%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%09%09%20%20%3C%21--group%20tag%20can%20be%20removed%2C%20it%20was%20just%20for%20understanding%2Fdebugging%20--%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%21--%3Cgroup%3E--%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%21--%20tail%20%3D%20Returns%20all%20but%20the%20first%20item%20in%20a%20sequence.%20--%3E%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22tail%28current-group%28%29%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%21--%3C%2Fgroup%3E--%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each-group%3E%0D%0A%09%09%3C%2Foutput%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22Row%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%21--%20if%20not%20using%20copy%2C%20can%20do%20this%3A%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CMeter%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22current-group%28%29%5B1%5D%21%28Meter%29%22%2F%3E%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CState%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22current-group%28%29%5B1%5D%21%28State%29%22%2F%3E%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22StartDate%22%2F%3E%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CVolume%3E%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22Volume%22%2F%3E%3C%2FVolume%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20--%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22current-group%28%29%5B1%5D%21%28Meter%2C%20State%29%2C%20*%20except%20%28Meter%2C%20State%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3CVendorFile%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fetc%2FVendorFile%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%20xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CMeter%3E123%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CState%3ETX%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CVolume%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%20xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CMeter%3E%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CState%3E%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%3E1%2F1%2F2024%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CVolume%3E100%3C%2FVolume%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%20xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CMeter%3E%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CState%3E%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%3E1%2F2%2F2024%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CVolume%3E110%3C%2FVolume%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%20xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CMeter%3E%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CState%3E%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%3E1%2F3%2F2024%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CVolume%3E107%3C%2FVolume%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%20xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CMeter%3E456%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CState%3EOK%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CVolume%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%20xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CMeter%3E%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CState%3E%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%3E1%2F1%2F2024%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CVolume%3E200%3C%2FVolume%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%20xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CMeter%3E%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CState%3E%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%3E1%2F2%2F2024%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CVolume%3E205%3C%2FVolume%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRow%20xmlns%3D%22%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CMeter%3E%3C%2FMeter%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CState%3E%3C%2FState%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CStartDate%3E1%2F3%2F2024%3C%2FStartDate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CVolume%3E210%3C%2FVolume%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRow%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FVendorFile%3E%20&input-type=XML)